# Update user newsletter subscriptions without being logged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a User model with authentication.

If logged in, the user can update his newsletter subscriptions preferences (i.e. option/optout)

However, I'd also like to give limited access to the page for the user who hasn't confirmed his account yet (through a link in an email).

He wouldn't be able to change any other information but the subscription preferences.

Right now, I can only unsubscribe a user from one newsletter.
What I'd like is to have a form with all the subscriptions available.

What would be the process to do so to make it secure?
(i.e. the user wouldn't be able to change the email/username to update another user from the link provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random SHA1 or MD5 hash using Ruby's [Digest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA1.html) module and inject it to the link you send out to the user.

Make sure to check the hash matches the user's email, a rough algorithm is as follows:

Create a hash for the user in question and store it in the database:

```
user.email_hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(user.email)
user.save
```

Within the controller method handling the email verification, check if the hash matches the user's details

```
if current_user.email_hash == params[:email_hash]
  # A match, process the activation and invalidate the hash
  user.activate
  user.invalidate_hash # This can set the email_hast to nil, for example.
else
  # Someone's trying to be sneaky, or accessing an invalidated hash
end
```

There are ways to make this more secure, for example having a combination of a user's username and email to create the hash, putting the endpoint behind a rate limit to prevent brute force attempts at guessing hashes, etc. but this should provide a good starting point.

Finally, don't forget to require the `digest\sha1` module (`require 'digest/sha1'`) in any files that need it.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that many newsletters use is to generate long random tokens and inject them into the link URLs provided in the e-mail. Each random token maps to an user; that way, by checking the token parameter, it is possible to get the user associated to that e-mail.

As an example, suppose the newsletter page is `/newsletters/settings`. The actual link sent by e-mail is `/newsletters/settings?code=12345678901234567890`, where the `code` parameter is different per user, or even per user **and** sent e-mail in some cases.

These tokens have security implications, though. For instance, if a newsletter is forwarded to another person because they forward the original e-mail. If they don't remove the links, third parties could impersonate the original user and manage the subscription as well.

Comment: if I understand correctly, this would be similar to a "password forgotten" link? (which I have and use a token for)